# Why List<SelectListItem> becomes null on post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to show a RadioButtonList in Asp.Net MVC 3.0. This is my extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        if (selectList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in selectList)
            {
                var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);
                var label = htmlHelper.Label(id, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text));
                var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = id });

                stringBuilder.AppendFormat("<div class=\"RadioButton\">{0}{1}</div>",radio.ToHtmlString(),label.ToHtmlString());
            }
        }
        return new MvcHtmlString(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

These are my HomeController action methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(GetIndexViewModel());
}

private IndexViewModel GetIndexViewModel()
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem> 
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = true, Value = "1", Text = "Sunday" },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false, Value = "2", Text = "Monday" },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false, Value = "3", Text = "Tuesday" },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false, Value = "4", Text = "Wednesday" },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false, Value = "5", Text = "Thursday" },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false, Value = "6", Text = "Friday" },
        new SelectListItem{ Selected = false, Value = "7", Text = "Saturday" },
    };
    return new IndexViewModel { SelectLists = list, SelectedItem = list[0] };
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel indexViewModel)
{
    return View(GetIndexViewModel()); //this works

    return View(indexViewModel); //why this doesn't work??
}
```

This is my index.cshtml:

```
@model IndexViewModel    

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2>Select any one item</h2>

    @Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(model => model.SelectedItem.Value, Model.SelectLists)

    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

I have commented which one works and which one doesn't. Basically my List becomes null. What am I doing wrong? If I have to do this everytime then it's better to use webforms because webforms can preserve data in postbacks. Using MVC basically means I have to make database call everytime the value is posted. Am I correct or there is some mistake in my code?

Comment: Is it so hard to write your parameter as camelCase?

Comment: @Phil: Sorry, I didn't get what you are saying ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you *bound* something in the GET action doesn't mean at all that it will be *bound* back to the same property in the POST action. The default model binder binds only what it sees in the Request. So if this information is not sent to the server when posting it will be lost.

Your custom helper generates a bunch of radio buttons and labels, but I can't see you anywhere generating input fields for the text properties. As a consequence they will be lost.

This being said your helper looks correct and in your POST action you should simply refetch this information from the datastore you feteched it initially if you want to redisplay the same view. So the correct way to do this is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel IndexViewModel)
{
    return View(GetIndexViewModel());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. So, basically you are saying I have to make a database call everytime. Right?

Comment: @Jaggu, no that's not what I am saying. I am saying that you should query your repository layer. Whether this repository layer does a database call is out of any interest. It could make a web service call or whatever. It could also handle caching so at the end of the day you would be refetching those values from the cache. The controller action doesn't care about that. Your data access layer is abstracted away from it. So all that it should do is to perform a repository method call.

Comment: Right Darin. Got it. Thanks. Caching is the key here. I understand.